# Not so famous places to visit from Singapore under $500

Tags: budget, planning, southeast-asia, singapore

I am planning to go for a 4 day trip to some place in south-east Asia for the Chinese New Year holidays in February. But my budget is strictly around 500 SGD. So, are there any interesting places to visit in the region? Since Chinese New Year is a major festival in this part of the world, I prefer not going to famous places to avoid the higher ticket prices.

I have few plans.

1. Singapore to Jakarta and Jakarta to Yogyakarta by train and Yogyakarta back to Singapore
2. Singapore to Tioman Islands in Malaysia.

Are there any other places to see?

Unknown adventerous places will be wonderful and comfort is not a problem.

EDIT:
By Unknown and not so famous, I mean places which is not a popular option for the chinese holidays. I am looking for destinations like waterfalls, hiking places, less crowded beaches etc.

Comment: With $500 you can get VERY far and to many, many places, especially 'unknown' places.  Could you be more specific about what you'd like to see, and what you'd like to avoid?

Comment: Also, what qualifies as 'not so famous' for you? All the places that you've mentioned are fairly well-known!

Comment: @MarkMayo I am avoiding nothing. I just want to explore a new place other than sitting idle in home for 4 days.

Comment: You will most likely encounter traffic jams traveling out of and getting back in to Singapore by land during Chinese New Year. Realistically, you will be limited to air and, if you can get tickets, rail.

Answer (score 3):

[Lombok, Indonesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lombok) would be a good option.
It has almost same characteristic as Bali, however it's less crowded than Yogyakarta and Bali. Living cost should be cheaper than Bali, so 500 SGD is more than enough.

If you like to live in secluded island you can try [Gili Trawangan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gili_Trawangan), and for hiking I recommend Mount Rinjani.

[image]

Comment: flying to lombok is expensive! come on, they have a $500 limit.

Answer (score 2):

Lombok is definately great! You can climb the vulcano Mount Rinjani, or you can go snorkling or diving at Gilis Islands. It's a lot more peaceful then Bali and as beautiful.

There is another island close by, supposedly undiscovered, with a blue pebble beach, called Flores.

Spot Komodo dragons at Komodo Island (trips from Lombok available).

Easy way to travel are the ferries and air asia.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a boat from the Cruise terminal at Harbourfront to **Kukup** southwest of Johor Bahru, or from Marina South terminal to the **Southern Islands** for a short day trip to get away from the hustle and bustle of the city. Most of the locals also head to **Batam** (from the Harbourfront Cruise terminal) for a short getaway as well to enjoy the cheap seafood and the resort living.